# 1970s Greek Mythology schoolbooks with kids who “discover” mythology

Tags: story-identification, mythology

I am trying to recall the name of some educational workbooks and characters that would have been in circulation when I was in 3rd grade (United States **around 1974**).

These texts were part of the curriculum at the public school I attended and were used to teach Greek Mythology.  My recollection was that the books were centered around a couple of fictional kids who "discover" mythology or are led to it by uncovering secrets about it through "teenage sleuth" type adventures.  I can't recall for certain, but it seems like there may have been some kind of portal that allowed the kids to actually enter the Greek Mythology realm.

I recall the books had quite a few illustrations as you might expect in a grade school educational books.  The books were used as a vehicle to generate interest in mythology.

Comment: I've definitely seen over the course of my lifetime 2 different television programs, which match your description

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

[Sullivan Programmed Readers, McGraw-Hill publishers, Cynthia Buchanan](http://whatwasthatbook.livejournal.com/1454894.html)

BTW, the "these" link in the comments in the link above doesn't work. It goes to an eBay auction for an item that was taken down.

And a list of [libraries](http://www.worldcat.org/title/programmed-reading-book-1-21/oclc/2129342) in the US that actually have copies.

Okay, found this one on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B1FD6OK). Book 20 of the series.

[image]

Comment: These - http://www.phoenixlearningresources.com/Phoenix_Everyreaders___Greek_and_Roman_Myths-details.aspx? I can't tell whether they're quite the right ones...

Comment: Just edited my answer to add a photo.